# UserManager in ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In my project *HttpContext* is a member of Controller and I can use it in *AccountController : Controller*. But I can't access an information about current user in *ApiController* in contraction like

```asp
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

So how to write custom ApiController right?

In the method below *user* variable shows me null on breakpoint. How can I retrive current user if I know that hi is logined?

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = manager.FindById(userid);

        var data = new Person {Name = user.UserName, Age = 99};

        return Ok(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From within any controller method you can do this.GetRequestContext().User to get the currently authenticated user.  The static HttpContext.Current is not supported by WebApi.

Comment: Hi. What the full method?

Comment: Sorry, but IntelySence doesn't show me any GetRequestContext() method in ApiController child.

Comment: Also, why result of **var identity = User.Identity.Name;** is NULL ?

Comment: This also returns Null value: **string userEmail = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;**

Comment: I need the SignInManager in ApiController, how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

manager.FindById(userid) retrieves a user from the database as opposed to the current . To get the current user, simply access the User property within your ApiController:

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    IPrincipal GetCurrentUser(){
        return User;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
protected string UserId { get { return User.Identity.GetUserId(); } }
```